# Intercepting MongoDB calls using AspectJ in a Spring project

Tags: spring, aspectj, mongodb-java

I am using Spring and the MongoDB java driver and I am trying to intercept all calls on the mongo DBCursor object to view queries before they get executed.

I've been trying to do this using the aspject-maven-plugin for external jars.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/weaveJars.html

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
         <verbose>true</verbose>
      <privateScope>true</privateScope>
      <complianceLevel>1.5</complianceLevel>
        <weaveDependencies>
        <weaveDependency>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </weaveDependency>
      </weaveDependencies>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I am already using Spring AOP and have aspecj configured in java code

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```

I am then adding the following to a class which uses the @Aspect annotation. (Other intercepts are working fine on custom classes which are in the source code of my project)

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.mongodb.DBCursor..*.*(..))")
public void interceptAndLog(ProceedingJoinPoint invocation){

          _loggingService.Info("intercepted DBCursor");

 }
```

I have also tried replacing @Pointcut with @Before but neither work.

Thanks in advance,

Ronan

Comment: A) A pointcut should have an empty body because it does not do anything, but should be referenced by an advice. B) A before advice does not fit with a ProceedingJoinPoint, because the latter belongs to an around advice.